# How to mass update a field on User Record

Tags: update, record

I am trying to update a field on all users in the organization. Ex: I would like to update the company name for all users in my organization.

I tried these:
- Create a list view of all users and try to mass update by double clicking but I am unable to (P.S: I enabled enhanced lists and inline editing from Setup > User Interface)

- I tried to do this from Developer Console:

list abc = [ Select Title From Users ];
for(Users abc : abc) {
    abc.title = 'Hello';
}
update abc;

Even this didn't work

Can someone please help me on this.

I am a newbie to salesforce community

Comment: how many users are there in the org?

Comment: there are more than 100. I tried exporting records to Excel, update and importing back which kind of works for now but I would like to know is there any inbuilt functionality either declaratively or programatically to solve this

Comment: do you have experience with SQL? (i didn't mean SOQL, i really mean SQL!) and i am asking this for a reason. coz there is this very nice tool which you can use to fire update/delete soqls without worrying about all the code.

Comment: I have a very little knowledge on SQL. But if you can share me the infomation on tool, I will try to look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please query id as well.

```
List abc = [ Select id,Title From User ]; 
for(User abc : abc) 
{ abc.title = 'Hello'; } 
update abc;
```

Comment: I tried to do this but on Execution getting the following error:
sObject type 'Users' is not supported.

Comment: please use user not users.

Answer (score 2):

I am a huge fan of [SQLForce](https://code.google.com/p/sqlforce/wiki/SQLForce) . Of course, there are lot of ways using which records could be updated. However, it is always good to keep few utilities handy like this one. If you have experience of SQLs, you would really feel the pain and miss the update and delete dmls in Salesforce (and of course there is reason for that!). However, using SQLForce you can continue using the same syntax on salesforce and fire update/delete SQLs.

Once you are connected to the org, an update that you have requested would simply look like this:

```
update user set title='Hello';
```

Thats it! This would update all the user records (coz there is no where clause!). Quite handy for those who are comfortable with SQLs.

Comment: Thanks Rajiv for your input. Will definitely look into this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just talking about a few records you could do this:

List myobjects = [ Select Id, CompanyName From User ];
for( User myobject : myobjects )
{
    myobject.CompanyName = 'xxxxxxx';
}

update myobjects;

You could also use dataloader, i.e. extract the records, update the value to true and then update with data loader if you don't want to use Apex

Comment: same error Varun. "sObject type 'Users' is not supported. " when tried from console. I am installing dataloader to see if it is easier than excel. But I am interested in knowing the industry standards on how they update if there are tons of records

Comment: sObject type 'Users' is not supported should not be the error. Looks like you are using users in the query.

Comment: The Industry standard is you have to either use a batch apex class or use data loader tool to update records in salesforce.

Comment: Thanks Varun for your inputs. That will be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Me & my admins usually use the Smart-Mass-Update app (instead of writing dedicated code each time and throw it 30 minutes after...)

http://www.zaapit.com/page/smart-mass-update

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4KmAEAV

[image: Mass Update / Edit Mode]